# Spark executor failure on mesos agent while using mesos dispatcher in cluster mode

Tags: apache-spark, mesos

I launched dispatcher as follows and the launch was successful as seen from the logs

```
./sbin/start-mesos-dispatcher.sh --master mesos://10.0.0.6:5050
```

Rest server was activated on port 7078

I submitted the job to the dispatcher as follows

```
./bin/spark-submit \
  --class com.ibm.cds.spark.samples.HelloSpark \
  --master mesos://10.0.0.6:7078 \
  --deploy-mode cluster \
  --verbose \
  https://github.com/../helloSpark.jar
```

On the spark slave, I get the following error in mesos agent sandbox - stderr.

```
17/11/22 09:22:06 INFO RestSubmissionClient: Submitting a request to launch an application in mesos://10.0.0.6:5050.
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.deploy.rest.SubmitRestProtocolException: Malformed response received from server
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.rest.RestSubmissionClient.readResponse(RestSubmissionClient.scala:268)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.rest.RestSubmissionClient.org$apache$spark$deploy$rest$RestSubmissionClient$$postJson(RestSubmissionClient.s
```

Question:
why is the executor submitting the launch of application to mesos-master? In spark-submit (above), I clearly give spark master address (at port 7078). why is this not taken?

How can I avoid this error?

using mesos version 1.4.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

removed all entries in spark-defaults.conf except the below.
spark.eventLog.enabled           true

It works fine now, meaning, I dont get this error.

looks like having a spark.master called out in spark-defaults.conf was causing this issue.